# Beautiful-soup find_all isnt able to grab anything for a particular link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying this code, but I don't know why it isn't outputting anything :

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s=requests.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN789IN790&ei=iWj5WouoDsfGvgSr16bwDg&q=United+States%09KEEP+SMILIN+FAMILY+DENTAL%092281+N+ZARAGOZA+RD+STE+102&oq=United+States%09KEEP+SMILIN+FAMILY+DENTAL%092281+N+ZARAGOZA+RD+STE+102&gs_l=psy-ab.12...1153407.1153407.0.1154512.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.YvWjU-kIBUs")
soup =BeautifulSoup(s.content,'html.parser')

#zloOqf, kpS1Ac, vk_gy : Tried all of these tags one by one but none worked
soup.find_all("div",{"class":"kpS1Ac"})

Out [30] : []
```

Even this doesn't work :

```
soup.findAll("span",{"class":'YhemCb'})
Out [30] : []
```

Required output :

```
Dental clinic in El Paso, Texas
```

Comment: You have got two qualified answers in your post and still you don't feel like making any comment or accepting either of them @vinita. Is there any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got empty results is because it's missing from your response.content. In order to get this part try adding Headers to requests.get().

```
HEADERS = {
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6",
          }
s = requests.get(<your_url>, headers=HEADERS)
soup =BeautifulSoup(s.content,'html.parser')
soup.findAll("span",{"class":'YhemCb'})
```

Output:

```
[<span class="YhemCb">Dental clinic in El Paso, Texas</span>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add headers in requests and call correct class i.e; `zloOqf kpS1Ac vk_gy` in `BeautifulSoup` module:

```
#code:

import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN789IN790&ei=iWj5WouoDsfGvgSr16bwDg&q=United+States%09KEEP+SMILIN+FAMILY+DENTAL%092281+N+ZARAGOZA+RD+STE+102&oq=United+States%09KEEP+SMILIN+FAMILY+DENTAL%092281+N+ZARAGOZA+RD+STE+102&gs_l=psy-ab.12...1153407.1153407.0.1154512.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.YvWjU-kIBUs"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup =BeautifulSoup(s.content,'html.parser')

data=  soup.findAll("div",{"class":"zloOqf kpS1Ac vk_gy"})
print data
final_output=  data[0].find("span")
print final_output.text
```

#### output:

```
Dental clinic in El Paso, Texas
```